# Is `constructor` property of an object relavent for the `instanceOf` operator

Tags: javascript

MDN states that:

> The instanceof operator tests presence of constructor.prototype in
>   object's prototype chain.

```
// defining constructors
function C(){}
function D(){}

var o = new C();

// true, because: Object.getPrototypeOf(o) === C.prototype
o instanceof C;
```

Okay, let's change `constructor` property:

```
function Z() {}
o.constructor = Z;
o instanceof C; // still returns true
```

Why?

Comment: Because it's an instance of `C`. `o instanceof Z` will still give false.

Comment: @andlrc, _Because it's an instance of C_ - how is this determined?

Comment: `C.prototype` is part of the chain that `o` have inherented. Same as `o instanceof Object` is true.

Comment: I understand that, my question is specifically how is it determined by javascript? By what references/mechanism?

Comment: `o.__proto__ === C.prototype` and `o.__proto__.__proto__ === Object.prototype`

Comment: so the answer to my question would be that `constructor` property is irrelevant? according to your comment the steps would be: `o._proto_ === C.prototype -> if false -> o._proto_._proto_ === C.prototype -> if false -> o._proto_._proto_._proto_ === C.prototype` - is that correct?

Comment: @andlrc, can you take a look please at my previous comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the sentence

> The instanceof operator tests presence of constructor.prototype in object's prototype chain.

`constructor` does not refer to the [constructor property on Object.prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor) but to the [right hand side parameter to the instanceof operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof)

setting `o.constructor = Z` does not change anything about that. You could change the `[[Prototype]]` of the object `o` using `Reflect.setPrototypeOf` or `Object.setPrototypeOf`

To demonstrate the behavior of `instanceof`:

```
var proto = {}
var o = Object.create(proto)
function t() {}
t.prototype = proto
o instanceof t // --> true
```

In this example `t` has to be a function because the [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-instanceofoperator) defines that it has to be callable.

---

As you might see a new behavior for the `instanceof` operator was introduced in ES2015. The `hasInstance` Symbol can now be used to control the behavior of `instanceof`. But if `hasInstance` is not defined the old behavior is used.

With the `hasInstance` Symbol you can for example create a "constructor" that returns true for all possible Objects.

```
let c = ({[Symbol.hasInstance]: () => true})
null instanceof c //true
{} instanceof c //true
NaN instanceof c //true
7 instanceof c //true
```

Comment: so is my [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37654417/is-constructor-property-of-an-object-relavent-for-the-instanceof-operator#comment62788857_37654417) statement correct?

Comment: yes. Except that the property is called `__proto__` and not `_proto_`